# Scrapy broad crawl returning error "filedescriptor out of range in select()"

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to run a simple broad crawl on 2,000 domains using Scrapy.

I have 4 lists of 500 domains each then I simple run the process.crawl on these 4 lists.
I'm just **scraping** their homepage for now.

The issue is after the 1,000 first domains, I start getting the following error ("filedescriptor out of range in select()"):

```
2019-10-20 00:24:59 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://www.******.com>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 44, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request, spider=spider)))
twisted.internet.error.ConnectError: An error occurred while connecting: [Failure instance: Traceback: <class 'ValueError'>: filedescriptor out of range in select()
```

> Note: replaced the domain with ****** in the error

Below is my function:

```
import scrapy
class scan_scripts(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'scan_scripts'

    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 500,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 25,
        'CONCURRENT_ITEMS': 50,
        'REACTOR_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE': 500,
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
        'LOG_LEVEL': 'ERROR',
        'HTTPCACHE_ENABLED': False,
        'COOKIES_ENABLED': False,
        'SCHEDULER_PRIORITY_QUEUE': 'scrapy.pqueues.DownloaderAwarePriorityQueue',
        'RETRY_ENABLED': False,
        'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': 15,
        'REDIRECT_ENABLED': False,
        'AJAXCRAWL_ENABLED': True,
        'DEPTH_PRIORITY': 1,
        'SCHEDULER_DISK_QUEUE': 'scrapy.squeues.PickleFifoDiskQueue',
        'SCHEDULER_MEMORY_QUEUE': 'scrapy.squeues.FifoMemoryQueue'
    }

    def start_requests(self):

        for domain in self.domains:
            yield scrapy.Request("https://" + domain, self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):

        print('### SCANNED: %s', (response.request.url))
```

Then I run this:

```
process = CrawlerProcess({})
    
process.crawl(scan_scripts, domains=domains_list1)
process.crawl(scan_scripts, domains=domains_list2)
process.crawl(scan_scripts, domains=domains_list3)
process.crawl(scan_scripts, domains=domains_list4)
    
process.start()
```

Comment: ulimit issue maybe? What OS is this?

Comment: I'm running MacOS Mojave 10.14.5

Comment: check [this post](https://medium.com/mindful-technology/too-many-open-files-limit-ulimit-on-mac-os-x-add0f1bfddde)

Comment: You’ll have to use a lower concurrency unless you can change the maximum open file limit of your system or switch to a different system that has a higher limit.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to set your `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` to a small value